# Core Data - serve data to website?

Tags: core-data

I am designing a server that accepts network clients from native apps and can transact with them, resulting in data held on the server.  I'm strongly considering using Core Data for this data store.

I also want a website to exist that could give users read-only access to information.

How can I achieve this sharing of data between separate processes (or even servers, potentially) using Core Data?  Also, how can I actually pull info from a Core Data store to display on a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is not a database engine. It is an API for constructing the model layer of a Model-View-Controller design app. As such it has no mechanisms for concurrency or other multiuser database features. You could certainly create a server with Core Data but it would be a small dedicated server which would support only a handful of clients.

The best design would be to use Core Data in the client apps but to serve the data using a dedicated server platform. You can send the information back and forth however you like e.g. JSON.